depthimage_to_laserscan only work with depth resolution 640*400
When I using depthimage_to_laserscan in ROS2 humble,I met error like:could not convert depth image to laserscan:scan_height( 1 pixels)is too large for the image height.I found that when I change my camera depth resolution to 640400,it works fine.But my camera didn't fit with 640400,why can't I use other resolution?
